# Iterating over hashmap contained as value within hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap

I have one parent HashMap
like 
`Hashmap<String, Hashmap<String,Arraylist<Customclass>>>`
Now itertaing over first hashmap that is parent hashmap gives me values like

key1-------[key of subHashmap(value)]
key2-------[key of subHashmap(value)]
.
.
.
Now I want to iterate over hashmap that is in values of parent hashmap based on their keys.

How I would be able to achieve this.
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<CustomClass>> entry : outerHashMap.entrySet()) {
String entryKey= entry.getKey();
// ...
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<CustomClass> nestedentry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
    String name = nestedEntry.getKey();
    ArrayList<CustomClass> value = nestedEntry.getValue();
    // ...
}
}
```